# Is there an IRAM satellite that measures thermal radiation at 250 GHz, or was this a ground-based instrument?

Tags: radio-astronomy, space-telescope, radio-telescope, infrared

The Nature Research Letter [A Pluto-like radius and a high albedo for the dwarf planet Eris from an occultation](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature10550) (also [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/47105166.pdf) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51749198_A_Pluto-like_radius_and_a_high_albedo_for_the_dwarf_planet_Eris_from_an_occultation)) says about half-way through:

> We now reassess Eris’ surface temperature in the light of our new results. Measurements by the Spitzer<sup>22</sup> and IRAM<sup>11</sup> satellites imply disk-averaged brightness temperatures of T<sub>b</sub>=30±1.2 K and T<sub>b</sub>=38±7.5 K at 70 and 1,200 mm, respectively.
>
> - <sup>11</sup>Bertoldi,F.F.Altenhoff,W.Weiss,A.,Menten,K.M.&Thum,C.Thetrans-neptunian object UB313 is larger than Pluto. Nature 439, 563–564 (2006).
> - <sup>22</sup>Stansberry, J. et al. in The Solar System beyond Neptune (eds Barucci, M. A., Boehnhardt, H., Cruikshank, D. P. & Morbidelli, A.) 161–179 (Univ. Arizona Press, 2008).

The caption of Figure 1 of reference 11 (Bertoldi et al. 2006) mentions:

> The 117-element MAMBO-2 camera has an effective frequency for thermal radiation of 250 GHz, a half-power bandwidth of 80 GHz (210–290 GHz), and a beam size of 10.7 arcsec (corresponding to 760,000 km at a distance of 96 AU).

and I think it refers to

- [Welcome to the home of MAMBO; the "Max-Planck-Millimeter-Bolometer"](https://astro.uni-bonn.de/%7Ebertoldi/projects/mambo/)
- [IRAM/MAMBO2.250GHz](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/svo/theory/fps/index.php?id=IRAM/MAMBO2.250GHz&&mode=browse&gname=IRAM&gname2=MAMBO2#filter)

**Question:** Is the use of the word *satellites* in "Measurements by the Spitzer<sup>22</sup> and IRAM<sup>11</sup> satellites..." correct, or does the latter refer to terrestrial measurments?

Comment: Nice Question !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nature paper by Bertoldi et al. (2006) says:

> Our millimetre observations were performed with the Max-Planck Millimeter Bolometer (MAMBO-2) array detector at the IRAM 30 m telescope on Pico Veleta, Spain.

This is a ground-based telescope in the Spanish Sierra Nevada mountains at 2850m to try and get above as much of the precipitable water vapor, which has a very large effect on sub-mm observations, as possible. Its website is [here](https://www.iram-institute.org/EN/30-meter-telescope.php)

Since it's common to refer to the Spitzer and its predecessor, the [IRAS mission](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/infrared-astronomical-satellite-iras/), when discussing far-infrared observations, I suspect the authors typed "IRAM", thought "IRAS (satellite)" and made a simple typo that was not caught before publication.